# CakePHP application as a backend for mobile applications

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have been developing this cakePHP application for browsers, but now there is a need to support some of the functions to serve android and iOS apps and I just cannot get reliable information of how to get it running. So for example this is one the functions that have to support mobile applications:

```
function add() {

    if (!empty($this->data) ) {
        $this->Customer->create();
        if ($this->Customer->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Customer is saved'), 'positive_notification');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'customers', 'action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Customer was not saved. Please try again'), 'negative_notification');
        }
    }
}
```

So as I understand, the call to the function can be done by POST from an app (correct me if I am wrong). But then different return should be given depending on the device.

Or is it better to expose different functions for different clients?

Any help, guidance or suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: _What_ exactly do you need to return to _which_ device type and _why_? As it stands your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: Basically I need an advice of what path to take in order to support mobile apps. Is it through REST? Or is there another way? Should there be different actions for different returns or can they be double-legged.

Comment: Why would you treat mobile apps any different at all? What makes their HTTP requests different to those from any other user agent? It's not possible to answer your question properly without knowing what exactly you need to do and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the function you posted:

- the function will be supposed to save a customer based on the data it receives, and return a response
- you will not be able to use `$this->redirect` or `setFlash`
- you will (probably) return JSON responses.

The function could look something like

```
public function add() {
     $response = array(
        'status' => false,
        'message' => __('Customer was not saved. Please try again')
    );

    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Customer->create();
        if ($this->Customer->save($this->data)) {
            $response = array(
               'status' => true,
               'message' => __('Customer is saved')
            );
        }
    }
    $this->set(array(
        'response' => $response ,
        '_serialize' => array('response')
    ));
}
```

If you want to have the same CakePHP application power both a website and an API, you could use different controllers for each one: a Customer Controller for the website and an 
APICustomer Controller for the API that works differently.

Depending on what you need, you could also have two CakePHP applications that share the models.

There are quite a few resources about how to make an API powered by CakePhp, like [this one](http://miftyisbored.com/complete-restful-service-client-cakephp-tutorial/) or [this one](http://hantsy.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/create-restful-application-with.html)

Comment: Thanks, that was all I needed. Hopefully it is going to be helpful for somebody in the future as well.